# Answer from within a network request

Tags: javascript, node.js, dialogflow-es

I have the following code

```
function search(agent){
  var term = agent.parameters.searchphrase;

  ddg.query( term, function( err, data ){
    var answer = data.AbstractText;
    var imageUrl = data.Image;
    var source = data.AbstractSource;
    var moreUrl = data.AbstractURL;
    var heading = data.Heading;
    console.log( answer );
    agent.add( 'anything' );
    console.log( 'smh' );
    agent.add( answer );
    agent.add( new Card( {
        title: heading,
        imageUrl: imageUrl,
        text: answer,
        buttonText: 'More about this',
        buttonUrl: moreUrl
      } )
    );
    agent.add( 'Answer provided by DuckDuckGo and ' + source );
  } );
}
```

When I try to call `agent.add` from within the callback it won't work, though everything else in there works.

When I call it from outside it works just fine.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For intent handlers that perform asynchronous operations (such as a network call that gets a callback), you must return a Promise object to indicate that you need to wait for the Promise to be completed before returning results.

It isn't clear if your `ddg` object can return a Promise, but you can wrap the Promise in a callback with something like

```
function search(agent){
  var term = agent.parameters.searchphrase;

  return new Promise( function( resolve, reject ){
    ddg.query( term, function( err, data ){
      if( err ){
        reject( err );
      } else {
        // Put the previous body of your callback here, concluding with...
        resolve();
      }
    })
  });
}
```

Comment: IT WOOOOORKS. Thank you so much